# Will repeatedly applying the following operation always leads to an odd number divisible by $3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, collatz-conjecture

Let:

- $x_i > 1$ be any odd integer that is not divisible by $3$
- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$
- $x_{i-1} =  \begin{cases}
  \text{undefined}, && \text{if }x_i\equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
  \frac{4x_i - 1}{3}, && \text{if }x_i\equiv 1 \pmod 3\\
  \frac{2x_i - 1}{3}, && \text{if }x_i\equiv 2 \pmod 3\\
  \end{cases}$

When defined, $x_{i-1}$ is an odd integer such that $x_i$ results from applying the collatz operation for odd integers since:

$$x_i = \frac{3x_{i-1} + 1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_{i-1}+1)}}$$

Note:  Details on the collatz operation for odd integers are found in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Syracuse_function).

Since each $x_{i-1}$ is either divisible by $3$ or it has a predecessor $x_{i-2}$, for any $x_i$, either there exists an integer $c$ where $x_{i-c} \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or there is an infinite sequence where no such $c$ exists.

It seems to me that it should be straight forward to show that $c$ exists for any such $x_i$.  When I try to prove this, I am finding that the argument is trickier than I expected.

Is there a straight forward argument to show that there always exists some integer $c$ so that the sequence is never infinite.  Or is this problem more challenging than it would appear on first glance?

I checked the Wikipedia article on the [Collatz conjecture in reverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#In_reverse) but did not find any information related to my question.

---

Update:  Added $x_i > 1$ which was implied since for $x_i=1$, $\dfrac{4(1)-1}{3}=1$ and $x_i=-1$, $\dfrac{2(-1)-1}{3}=-1$.

---

Update 2: Restated the title to replace "Collatz Operation in reverse" with the "following operation" which is then defined in the question.

Gottfried Helms has pointed out that this statement was not accurate.

Comment: Hmm, after fiddling a bit on it, I'd like to mention, it would be better to explicitely mention, that your operation is *not* a reversal of the Collatz-transformation rule, but only of a specific subcase *(for instance to mention this in the title: A full inverse would not only have the $4x_i-1$ and $2x_i-1$ branches but also that of the larger powers of $2$. That made my initial fiddlings inaccurate...)*

Comment: Great point.  I will update the question as you suggest.

Comment: 1) It might be that this is of the same complexity as the 3x+1-problem is, because if you look at negative numbers and use $-5$and $-7$ then you get into the cycle, and on no iteration you'll arive at a number divisible by $3$. Similarly a contradiction should occur if in the positive numbers there is a cycle: then a number divisible by 3 should not be reached. (Maybe the same argument would follow if some divergent sequence would exist in the Collatz-problem)

Comment: 2) I looked at my (excel-) sheet at http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collatzgraphs.htm, which shows the tree of the backwards iterations (on odd numbers only). The numbers are red if $=1 \pmod 3$ , green if $=2 \pmod 3$ and grey if $=0 \pmod 3$. If red, an arrow goes upwards, if green downwards and if grey, no arrow origins. Your problem can be vizualised, when we start at any number, follow the arrows along the leading numbers in the rows and look whether always a grey number concludes the trajectory.

Comment: For instance, for starting at *5* as well as for starting at *85* we see immediately the ending of the trajectories at numbers divisible by *3*. *If* the collatz conjecture is true, all odd numbers are in the tree; if not we have independent sister-trees originating at some unknown cycle-of-numbers (like the tree beginning at the roots $-5$ and $-7$ in the negative numbers which is independent of the the tree with single root at $-1$). So while we might be able to show your property in this tree, that each so far discussed trajectory ends at a grey number, we do not know,  ...

Comment: ... whether cycles exist and thus counterexamples for your problem.  *(P.S.: Just for the record: the given link is sub-page of the discussion at http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm)*